# Genymotion in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-sdk

Is there anybody to help me?
I've installed Virtualbox and Genymotion on Ubuntu successfully. 
Then I selected Samsung Galaxy s5 4.4.2 on Genymotion, downloaded it succesfully either,
but I've got problems in installation of APK. So I did genymotion translation 1.1 and gapps-kk, but yet my APK didn't work. When I started Genymotion appeared viber, tango, Google service, etc, but unfortunately it has stopped.

Comment: Are you still troubleshooting this? Can you explain what is happening and how that compares to what you expect to see happening?